# Wait for function to setState before triggering next function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
async componentDidMount() {
    this.loadSelectors();
    this.useSelectors();
};


loadSelectors = () => {
    this.setState({"Selector": "Test"});
}

useSelectors = () => {
    console.log(this.state.Selector);
}
```

How do I wait for `loadSelectors()` to finish setting the state before I call `useSelectors()`? I know the normal  way to do this is

```
this.setState({"Selector": "Test"}, => this.useSelectors());
```

but my case seems different, I've tried

```
async componentDidMount() {
    await this.loadSelectors(() => useSelectors());
}
```

and It does not work.

Comment: Why _would_ that work? loadSelectors doesn't define any parameters, it certainly doesn't deal with a callback being passed to it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's just a simple example to ask the question. my actual function is longer and much of it is not necessary as the main question is what I have posted

Comment: So does your implementation actually attempt to invoke the callback? If it does you should _show that_, or the example is useless.

Comment: @jonrsharpe better?

Comment: As far as we can see loadSelectors indeed doesn't take any parameters, certainly not a callback, so why you're passing a function to it and expecting that to do anything at all is unclear.

Comment: It's just a simple question, not sure what else I can do to make it clearer...

Comment: `loadSelectors` doesn't return anything, let be a promise that can be awaited.

Comment: @trincot I `setState` in `loadSelectors` and would like to use the values that I've set in another function.

Comment: I know you do. Just saying that `await` will not do what you want when the expression that follows it does not resolve to a promise. That's the first thing to look into -- `loadSelectors` must return a promise, but it just returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out what I needed, just pass the `useSelectors` function as a callback function and use it in `loadSelectors`

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.loadSelectors(() => this.useSelectors());
};


loadSelectors = (callbackFunction) => {
    this.setState({"Selector": "Test"}, callbackFunction);
}

useSelectors = () => {
    console.log(this.state.Selector);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to *promisify* `this.setState`, but `loadSelectors` does not return anything. It should return a promise that resolves when the callback -- that should be passed to `setState` -- is called:

```
var loadSelectors = () => new Promise(resolve =>
    this.setState({"Selector": "Test"}, resolve)
);
```

One rule to follow when you use `await`: if the goal is to await a certain future event, then the expression that follows it should be a promise, as otherwise there is not going to be much awaiting.

Comment: Thanks Trincot, I'm still fairly new to React, just started learning about it 2 months ago. Thanks so much for your answer, will try it tomorrow and accept as answer if it works.